# como saber lo que viene despues de un caracter en especifico en una cadena en python

Tags: python

por ejemplo tengo esta cadena 
el carro rojo.
y quiero saber si después de ese . viene otra palabra
había pensado en esta solución

```
cadenaaux = "el carro rojo.casa"
if (cadenaaux.count('.') > 0 and cadenaaux[-1] != '.'):
```

pero la ultima posición de esa cadena me la da vacía y no se porque deveria devolverme el ultimo carácter que seria 'a' pero no entonces no se si habría alguna función establecida que me ayudara

Comment: En python 3 me funciona tal como estás esperando `cadenaaux[-1] = 'a'`

Comment: lo que pasa es que tomo esa cadena de un archivo.txt y cada oracion viene linea por linea @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas leyendo de un txt como dices el problema posiblemente sea que el último carácter es un salto de linea '\n' o retorno de carro `\r` y no lo estas eliminando. No es un carácter vacío sino '\n' o `\r`.

Si tenemos el siguiente txt llamado `datos.txt` a modo de ejemplo:

> el carro rojo.casa
>   el carro azul.garaje

Si lo leemos de esta forma:

```
data = open('datos.txt')

print('Imprimiendo última letra de cada línea:')
for cadenaaux in data:
    print(cadenaaux[-1])
data.close()
```

La salida es :

> ```
> Imprimiendo última letra de cada línea:
>
>
> e
> ```

En este caso la primera cadena, si es un archivo con el fin de linea al estilo Windows, es en realidad:

> el carro rojo.casa\r\n

Esto hace que nos imprima un salto de linea (el otro se debe al `print`).

Para evitar esto lo que se hace es eliminar los saltos de linea/retornos de carro de cada línea. Para ello se usa `str.strip()`:

```
data = open('datos.txt')

print('Imprimiendo última letra de cada línea:')
for cadenaaux in data:
    cadenaaux = cadenaaux.strip()
    print(cadenaaux[-1])
data.close()
```

Salida:

> Imprimiendo última letra de cada línea:
>   a
>   e

=========

En cuanto a tu problema en concreto, puedes usar `if (cadenaaux.count('.') > 0 and cadenaaux[-1] != '.'):` pero ten en cuenta que por ejemplo:

> el carro rojo.casa.

no cumpliría la condición.

Otra opción sería usar expresiones regulares también:

```
import re

if re.search(r'\w\.\w', cadenaaux):
```

Si quieres obtener los substrings separados por los puntos puedes recurrir a `re.split()` o `str.split()`:

```
cadenaaux = "el carro rojo.casa"
subcadenas= [s for s in cadenaaux.split('.') if s]
print(subcadenas)
```

Salida:

> ['el carro rojo', 'casa']